# How to get value from combobox swing in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have an assignment to create a swing GUI that creates a sequential file, and another swing GUI that reads the sequential file. I don't know how to take value from combobox. Let's say the name of the combobox is comboBox_1, what is the command?

```
      if ( studentID > 0 )  {

                //***********************
                output.writeUTF(textField.getText());
                output.writeUTF(textField_1.getText());
                output.writeUTF(textField_2.getText());
                output.writeInt(studentID);
                output.writeUTF(textField_4.getText());
                output.writeUTF(textField_5.getText());
                output.writeUTF(textField_6.getText());
                output.writeUTF(textField_7.getText());
                output.writeUTF(textField_8.getText());
                //PLACE FOR COMBOBOXES

                output.writeInt(maths);
                output.writeInt(buisness);
                output.writeInt(programming);
                output.writeInt(accounting);
                output.writeInt(art);
                output.writeInt(music);
              }
```

Comment: Have you checked the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html)?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html getSelectedValue() is what you are looking for. Do your own research before asking for help. You'll learn a lot more and remember it better if you find the answer on your own.

Comment: I have done my own research f, but the thing is i have to get the value by pressing an "enter Button", my gui is like a database with first name,last name,age, with JtextFields and JComboBoxes, and by pressing the enter button, it creates the sequential file, so i don't want to get the value when i choose from the combobox, but when i press enter.

Answer (score 0):

If your comboboxes contain list of strings,  you could do

```
(String)comboBox_1.getSelectedItem();
```